# java RMI - server automatically calling remote methods

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I'm trying to start an RMI program which will allow a server to send a client 3 questions and the client will take in answers and send them back to the server. So far on the server I send the question and get the answer, but the server automatically calls the getAnswer() method and that method doesn't store what the user enters.

This is the console results I get when I run server and client:

```
    Server Started
0
0
Client connected, sending acknowledgement
received answer from client: 3
```

As you can see it calls the getAnswer() method before the client even connected, hence why there are 2 values shown despite answers not being given.
How can I make the server only call those methods when I want them to? I've tried loops and if statements but nothing I can think of works!

Server code:

```
    import java.rmi.*;

public class Server
{

public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
{
    int answer1, answer2, answer3;

    System.out.println("Server Started");
    try
    {
        Implement obj = new Implement(); 
        Naming.rebind("remote", obj);//register name with registry


        obj.sendQuestion(question1);
        answer1 = obj.getAnswer();

        obj.sendQuestion(question2);
        answer2 = obj.getAnswer();


    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static String question1 = "Q1: (A+B)*(A+B)\n1. A*A+B*B\n2. A*A+A*B+B*B\n3. A*A+2*A*B+B*B";
static String question2 = "Q2: (A+B)*(A-B)\n1. A*A+2*B*B\n2. A*A-B*B\n3. A*A-2*A*B+B*B";
static String question3 = "";
}
```

Client code:

```
    import java.rmi.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Client
    {
      public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
    {

    try {
        Interface obj = (Interface)Naming.lookup("remote"); //looks for object with add in name
        Interface m = (Interface) obj;
        System.out.println(obj.sendMessage()); //retrieve message from server

        System.out.println(obj.receiveQuestion());
        System.out.println("Please enter your answer");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input = scan.nextInt();
        obj.test(input);
        System.out.println(obj.receiveQuestion());

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

}
```

Interface code:

```
    import java.rmi.Remote;

    public interface Interface extends Remote //becomes a remote interface
    {
    public String sendMessage() throws Exception;
    public void test(int message) throws Exception;
    public void sendQuestion(String message) throws Exception;
    public String receiveQuestion() throws Exception;
    public int getAnswer() throws Exception;

    }
```

Implementation code:

```
    import java.rmi.server.*;

public class Implement extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Interface

{
String msg;
int answer;

public Implement() throws Exception //constructor to handle exceptions
{
    super();
}

public String sendMessage()
{
    String msg = "You have connected to the server";
    System.out.println("Client connected, sending acknowledgement");
    return msg;     
}

public void sendQuestion(String message)
{
    msg = message;
}

public String receiveQuestion()
{
    return msg;
}

public void test(int message)
{
    answer = message;
    System.out.println("received answer from client: " +answer);
}

public int getAnswer()
{

    System.out.println(answer);

    return answer;
}
}
```

Comment: On the client console, even though I try to send question1 from the server first, question2 is sent both times

Answer (score 1):

You have this back to front. You're calling your own remote methods in the server. It is the *client* who should be calling the remote methods. From your description, you want your server to be a client, and your client a server.

Comment: I need to store the questions in the server code, so how else can I send the strings without calling a method?

Comment: I didn't say anything about not calling a method. I said you have your design back to front. Servers can't send messages to clients in RMI. Clients call servers, not the other way around.

Comment: RMI is (Client/Server model),  the stub(packages parameters, etc) is created in the server, which is called by the skeleton(unpacks stub and passed up to rmiregitry, etc) in the client.